# Developing for the Android tablet, with the physical tablet

Tags: android, tablet

I've been trying to work with the SDK emulator but it's ridiculous slowness has driven me insane. I am buying an Android tablet. What do I need to know about developing with an actual tablet? Is there a "developer mode"? How do I debug? Do I need any peripherals for development?

Comment: Nothing special required. On Windows you might need to install drivers for the tablet: http://d.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: I'm getting the new Toshiba Thrive... Should the 
"Fujitsu Toshiba" link cover that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just buy any Honeycomb tablet, your experience in developing will be pretty much same, just a lot faster on an actual tablet.
All you would have to do is install the ADB drivers and plug in the USB cable. Also USB debugging mode should be enabled.
Everything is as easy as cutting cheese.